# Django rest framework api testing returns empty result

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I am trying to make testing on Django Rest Framework API.
When i test URLs manually i get all kind of data which i want, but when i test it by APITestCase it returns empty results, in detail API page it returns "not found" error.
This is code:

```
class UsersTest(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.url = reverse('user:user-list')

    def test_fetch_users(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        response_data = json.loads(response.content)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertTrue(response_data.get('results'))

    def test_fetch_users_date_intervals(self):
        date_from = '2019-10-14'
        date_to = '2019-10-20'
        response = self.client.get(self.url, {'from': date_from, 'to': date_to})
        response_data = json.loads(response.content)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertTrue(response_data.get('results'))
```

Thanks

Comment: In tests, database is usually recreated from scratch and thus empty. What you need to do is add some data in the setUp() method .

Comment: @Borut, you are totally right, thanks a lot!